# Android bluetooth LE scan in background has a different behaviour

Tags: android, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I'm developing an app to keep scanning certain smart bluetooth LE tags to check when a tag is out of range.

I'm getting one signal from each tag per second when I'm running my code in foreground. But in background (like scanning in a service) this rate keeps decreasing down to 1 signal per 10 seconds!

I'm almost sure that the frequency of the smart tag is the same in both cases, but maybe the Android operating system slows down discovering bluetooth devices due to battery issues when the scan happens in the background.

I'm afraid that this will be not satisfying, especially when you need to detect a bag is being stolen or something critical that forces me to keep the rate at 1 signal per 3 seconds or so.

**UPDATE:**

For the code I used, first:

```
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothLeAdapter;
```

this for starting scanning:

```
bluetoothLeAdapter.startLeScan(LeScanCallback);
```

and this is the callback:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback LeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {

        Log.i("Found: ", device.getName() + " - " + device.getAddress());
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you share your scanning code?  I do not think this should work differently in the background if properly coded.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh so what did you finally find? Can you update your final sharing as well?

Comment: @PallavBakshi many years ago :) but I distinctly remember that I've ended up using `IntentService` but with a trick that keeps it running all the time just like a normal service.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.3 and 4.4 do not slow down discovery in the background.  In the [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library), I had to put in extra code to slow down scans to save battery when apps are in the background.

I cannot explain what you say you are seeing.  Perhaps you should try the library mentioned above and see if you see the same behavior.  It is open source, so you can look at the code, too.  It scans the same way as in your snippets in your question.

Comment: It's trade off, battery versus accuracy. I'll try the library anyway and tell you what I get. Thanks.